# useReducer does not trigger props update and re-render in child react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Changes to the child props with state change in the parent does not re-render child props.  I'm using useReducer to update state in parent.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong, please?

```
   const Parent = () => {
       const [localVar1, setLocalVar1]=useState('');
       
       const reducer = (state, action) => {
          switch(action.type){
                case "TWO":
                  let newState = {
                     ...state,
                     action.payload
                  };
                  return newState;
                default:
                  return state; 
          }
       }


const [currentObject, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, defaultInitialObject);

const updateObjecct = (param) => {
    let obj = param;
    setLocalVar1(obj.var1); //this triggers child re-render
    dispatch({type:"TWO", payload: { var2: "hello" }); //this does not trigger child re-render
}

useEffect(()=>{
   console.log(`current object has changed ${JSON.stringify(currentObject)}`);  //goes into this both times when setLocalVar1 called and when dispatch called
},[JSON.stringify(currentObject)]);

return (
    <Child dispatch={dispatch} object={currentObject} />
);
}

const Child = (props) => {
   const {object} = props;

   useEffect(()=>{
     console.log(`var1 changed ${object.var1}`); //this works
   },[object.var1]);
   
  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log(`var2 changed ${object.var2}`); //this does not work
  },[object.var2]);
}
```

Comment: You've a typo in your reducer code, `let newState = { ...state, action.payload };` should be `let newState = { ...state, ...action.payload };` where the payload is also spread into the state object. Voting to close as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the payload to the state not updating it, you can update var2 like this:

```
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'TWO':
            let newState = {
                ...state,
                var2: action.payload,
            };
            return newState;
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

And dispatch the payload to have only the value, not the key:

```
dispatch({type:"TWO", payload: "hello"});
```